# Counting number of paths

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursive-query

I have a table `trainschedule` that goes like:-

```
 train_id | source  | destination | distance | departure_time | arrival_time 
----------+---------+-------------+----------+----------------+--------------
 22435    | Kolkata | Bhopal      |     1200 | 08:00:00       | 17:00:00
 21484    | Mumbai  | Jaipur      |      500 | 13:23:44       | 13:23:45
 21424    | Delhi   | Mumbai      |      800 | 13:23:44       | 15:05:40
 12456    | Bhopal  | Mumbai      |      800 | 11:00:00       | 23:00:00
 12453    | Banaras | Mumbai      |      500 | 11:00:00       | 21:00:00
 21514    | Jaipur  | Madras      |     1500 | 10:05:00       | 13:23:45
 21414    | Delhi   | Kolkata     |      800 | 14:05:00       | 15:05:40
 23432    | Bhopal  | Hyderabad   |      670 | 12:00:00       | 20:20:00
(8 rows)
```

Given a source city, for example Delhi, destination city, for example Mumbai, I'm supposed to return the number of paths between these two cities.

I don't know how can I find that, all I was able to come up with was:-

```
with recursive path(f,t) as(
    select source,destination
    from trainschedule
    union
    select trainschedule.source,path.t
    from trainschedule,path
    where trainschedule.destination=path.f)
select t 
from path;
```

and it gives me all the cities that are reachable from a given city. I don't know how to proceed now. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What happens if two cities happen to have more than two possible route between them?  How does that get reported?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Is that some issue or a hint?

Comment: Why not just count(*) group by t?

Comment: @Fact it was incorrect...

Comment: Do you have a sample output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have done all the hard work in the recursive cte. There is just one change you need to make, which is to use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`, so that you get a row for **every** path from one city to another. Then you can just select each pair of cities and count the number of rows for that pair in the cte:

```
with recursive path(f,t) as(
    select source,destination
    from trainschedule
    union all
    select trainschedule.source,path.t
    from trainschedule,path
    where trainschedule.destination=path.f)
select f, t, count(*)
from path
group by f, t
order by f, t;
```

Output (for your sample data):

```
f       t           count
Banaras Jaipur      1
Banaras Madras      1
Banaras Mumbai      1
Bhopal  Hyderabad   1
Bhopal  Jaipur      1
Bhopal  Madras      1
Bhopal  Mumbai      1
Delhi   Bhopal      1
Delhi   Hyderabad   1
Delhi   Jaipur      2
Delhi   Kolkata     1
Delhi   Madras      2
Delhi   Mumbai      2
Jaipur  Madras      1
Kolkata Bhopal      1
Kolkata Hyderabad   1
Kolkata Jaipur      1
Kolkata Madras      1
Kolkata Mumbai      1
Mumbai  Jaipur      1
Mumbai  Madras      1
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3CpTxPxALRdXauAdVQiXQH/0)